# How to do a q-carousel with q-parallax images in Quasar

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am trying to setup a carousel for my home page with a carousel with some full screen images and parallax effect on them. I am new to quasar but have used vuetify quite often but recently switched to Vue3 so figured I would try out quasar. However, I am struggling to do this. I see there is a slot for QCarouselSlide but I am not sure how to tie into that for this parallax.

My code so far is as follows:

```
 <template>
  <q-page padding="false">
    <q-carousel
      v-model="slide"
      swipeable
      animated
      navigation-position="left"
      navigation
      padding
      style="height:100vh"
      class="bg-purple text-white rounded-borders"
    >
      <q-carousel-slide name="style" class="column no-wrap flex-center">
        <q-parallax src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg"></q-parallax>
      </q-carousel-slide>
      <q-carousel-slide name="tv" class="column no-wrap flex-center">
        <q-parallax src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg"></q-parallax>
      </q-carousel-slide>
    </q-carousel>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const slide = ref('style')

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following codepen.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/rNrrRxj

```
    <q-carousel-slide :name="1" class="column no-wrap">
      <div class="row fit">
        <q-parallax
          src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg"
        >
          <h1 class="text-white">Basic</h1>
        </q-parallax>
      </div>
    </q-carousel-slide>
```